# Do minimum wage laws disproportionally negatively affect African Americans and Hispanics?

Tags: united-states, politics, economics

I was listening to a podcast, and they said that an increase in minimum wage would disproportionally negatively affect African Americans and Hispanics in the US. The reason being is that when the minimum wage increases more people enter the labor market and some have better qualifications for jobs like more education. Since the employer is now paying the same amount for people both with and without, let's say, a high school diploma, they will pick the person that graduate high school. And since, on average, African Americans and Hispanics have less education(1) they lose out on potential employment. The podcast said this was from paper, but I have done some digging and haven't been able to find it.

This post is not a duplicate of [Do minimum wage laws create employment conditions that are racially biased against blacks?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10182/do-minimum-wage-laws-create-employment-conditions-that-are-racially-biased-again) because it is about academic research not the claims of an economist vs. an activist. This is more about the paper 1)if it exists and 2)if the methodology used is valid.

(1) Table 1 on this [report](https://www.census.gov/content/dam/Census/library/publications/2016/demo/p20-578.pdf) by US Census Bureau

Comment: The question is an exact duplicate: the claim is the same and the answers must present the best available evidence anyway. Maybe someone can boost the other question with a bounty if they think it deserves more attention. In any case, asking a more specific version of the question is not the way to go.

Comment: @Sklivvz - boosted. I was overdue for a bounty anyway, thanks for the idea.